# 301 Redirect with Space After .htm

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to do a 301 redirect in my .htaccess from "http://example.com/article.htm k" to "http://example.com/article.htm". I've tried doing,

```
Redirect 301 "http//example.com/article.html k" http://example.com/article.htm
```

as above and and with %20 and [\s] in place of the space for the k. None of these seem to work. I'm thinking the problem is because the space is after the .htm rather than before it. Any ideas on how to fix this or what the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: [RTFM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect): _“The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a slash.”_

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Redirect` as

```
Redirect 301 /article.html\ k http://example.com/article.htm
```

or use `RedirectMatch` (to specify a regex)

```
RedirectMatch 301 /article\.html\sk http://example.com/article.htm
```