# Htaccess 301 problems - aspx url with space %20

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

Moving an old aspx website to apache / php and I'm having trouble with creating some redirects because some of the old URLs have spaces %20 in them, and those 301 redirects are not working.

```
redirect 301 /useful-info/student%20visas.aspx http://www.newdomain.com/useful-student-info/
```

I have many URLs with %20 spaces so any script to fix all these together would be really useful. Can anyone suggest how I get around this problem?

Also, the new website is Wordpress and the only other code in the Htacces file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thanks,
Graham

Comment: This will probably easiest if you look for a WP plugin that will handle this for you … that you can simply provide with a list of “old” URLs and the new ones you want those mapped to.

Comment: This method here works (using redirectmatch, instead of redirect)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484235/301-redirect-with-space-after-htm

So I tried it on the URL below and it works fine, 

redirectmatch 301 /useful-info/student\svisas\.aspx http://www.iceireland.com/

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I will research a Wordpress plugin. Right now though I would like to do this directly with Htaccess (its a little urgent)